# calling a method of a Object inside Session without typecasing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a jar (xyz.jar) which is pluggable to 5 projects , all project creates a object in session when anyone login to any of those 5 application named "loginObject" , I have to use this object from session in "xyz.jar" but LoginObject class is in main project , because of which i am unable to typecast it to "loginObject" class.

```
EGlobalLoginBean loginObject=(EGlobalLoginBean ) httpSession.getAttribute("loginObject");
```

Now that class "EGlobalLoginBean " is in main project not "xyz" , so i am unable to typecast it , and as i can't typecast i am unable to call it's method.
I can't add main project as dependent project into "xyz" because it's suppose to happen the other way around.

All suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: btw if it helps , JSP inside that jar are able to access that session like "${loginObject.userPreferences.language}" , and yes JSPs are inside jar :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to work around it IMHO

1. Copy the .class file to the web-inf/classes of xyz.jar (if its a web application) or else add it to the server's classpath (bad, but it will work). Either way you have to extract the .class file (and its dependencies) out.
2. Load the .class file using a URL class loader, have it implement a common interface and invoke it's methods using the interface.

Comment: second one worked really well , created a interface in a common Jar , used class loader to get it's implementation from common web and stored it in interface in xyz.jar, though implementation of that interface needs to be written in all 5 projects , which is acceptable , kinda like proxy,Thanks Ramp.